# Adding a range of cells from 2 worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working code that allows me to add all sheets in a folder and pivot tables summing up an inventory form. I've now been tasked with trying to create a running total page where we can take a second worksheet and just add or subtract how many items are entered in the total row. I've pieced together this code which works to an extent of what I need.

```
Dim Add As Integer
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As Integer
var1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6").Value
var2 = Worksheets("add").Range("F6").Value
Add = var1 + var2
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("add").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
```

This however only works for a single cell and I need it to work for a range from D4 to D649 on Sheet1. I can't for the life of me think of the solution to this and I can't seem to find the solution in reference to multiple sheets and multiple cells.

Comment: What do you mean you need it to work on a range? Do you need to add each cell in `D4:D649` to `F6` on the other sheet?

Comment: Ah sorry. I have Sheet1 D4 - D649 as my running totals. I have my code add another sheet from another workbook and names the sheet to "add". Then I need it to add up any number entered on sheet "add" from F4 - F649 to my running total on Sheet1. Hopefully that clears it up

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you’re after this:

```
Dim i As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 4 To 649
        .Cells(i, 4) = .Cells(i, 4) + Worksheets("add").Cells(i, 6)
    Next
End With
```

Or

```
Dim i As Long
Dim sht1Vals As Variant, shtAddVals As Variant

sht1Vals = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D649").Value
shtAddVals = Worksheets("add").Range("F4:F649").Value
For i = 1 To 646
    sht1Vals(i, 1) = sht1Vals(i, 1) + shtAddVals(i, 1)
Next
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D649").Value = sht1Vals
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a loop to your code, see if it works:

```
Sub Macro7()

Dim Add As Integer
Dim var1 As Integer
Dim var2 As Integer
var1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6").Value
var2 = Worksheets("add").Range("F6").Value
Add = var1 + var2

t = 6

Do Until t = 649

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(t, 4).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = Add
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("add").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

t = t + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked perfectly with DisplayName's code Thank you very much though.

```
Dim i As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
For i = 4 To 649
    .Cells(i, 4) = .Cells(i, 4) + Worksheets("add").Cells(i, 6)
Next
End With
```